# Phusion Passenger Showing Environment Variables

Tags: environment-variables, passenger

I'm getting some Phusion Passenger errors with Ruby On Rails

Problem is it's showing my environment variables in the error report. This is great in development, but what happens if my server faulters in production?

Is there any way in Phusion Passenger to disable displaying the environment vars?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change to production mode.  The steps are outlined [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerappenv).  For nginx installations (like what I use) you need to set passenger_app_env to "production" in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf .  Here is an example of how it should look:

```
...
http {
    # Only for development purposes.
    # For production environment, set it accordingly (i.e. production vs development)
    # Remove this line when you upload an actual application.
    # For * TESTING * purposes only.
    passenger_app_env production;
    #passenger_app_env development;
    #passenger_friendly_error_pages off;
....
```

Comment: Please give sufficient information here to answer the question. Links break all the time so, the next time the Phusion Passenger website is reorganized, your answer will contain no information. Also, it's not very helpful to link somebody to a document that contains fifty screenfuls of information and say, "Look here."

Comment: @DavidRicherby isn't that plagerism?  I'll see what I can do to improve it, but I don't want to plagerize.

Comment: It's not plagiarism if you take only the small part you need and properly acknowledge your source, and your edit does both of these things. Thanks!

Comment: Any solution for Apache ? I have added `PassengerAppEnv "production"` in my VHost file, but it silll shows the full errog log (eg when database is down)